# Uncurrying function for tupel input returns error

Tags: haskell, dictionary, tuples

I'm writing this code where I need to uncurry a function in order for it to allow tuple valued input. This is my code:

```
printField :: Int -> String -> String
--the function to be uncurried

printRow :: [(Int, String)] -> String
printRow d = map (uncurry printField) d
```

But it's throwing me the following error and I have no idea why:

> ```
> Couldn't match type '[Char]' with 'Char'
> Expected type: Int -> String -> Char
>   Actual type: Int -> String -> String
> In the first argument of 'uncurry', namely 'printField'
> In the first argument of 'map', namely '<uncurry printField>'
> In the expression: map <uncurry printField> d
> ```

Does anyone know what this means and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,
Skyfe.

Comment: map has type `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. So printRows should return [String] and not String. or you meant to use concatMap ?

Comment: Aah that's right! Totally forgot to concat it, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Satvik already mentioned, use [`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aconcatMap).

And you can use eta reduction here and drop redundant `d`

`printRow = concatMap (uncurry printField)`